# Error Pulling A Field - Php / Sql

Tags: php, sql

Trying to pull fields 'info' and 'date' from Comment table.

Two Tables:
[image: professor]
[image: Comment]

**Php**

```
<?php
$pID2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $username = "###";
        $password = "####";
        $pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
        $pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
            SELECT info, date
            FROM Professor, Comment
            WHERE Professor.pID = ?');
        $sth2->execute(array(
            $pID2
        ));
?>
```

**While Statement**

```
while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
                echo "<div class='comment'>by Anonymous on {$row['date']}: <br> {$row['info']} </div>";
                }
```

The problem is, **it pulls results, but it shows those two same comments for all the professors**. Is there an error here with not calling a unique professor given the `pID=[somenumber]` in the url??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual SQL code should be:-

```
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
            SELECT info, date
            FROM Comment
            JOIN Professor ON Professor.pID = Comment.pID
            WHERE Comment.pID = ?');
```

You need to put a [`JOIN` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) with the `Professor` table.

Hope it helps.

**Update:-**
Another checking should have been provided (**as mentioned by the OP in the comment**). If no rows are found, then the [row count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) checking should be applied as:-

```
if ($sth2->rowCount()) {
  while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<div class='comment'>by Anonymous on {$row['date']}: <br> {$row['info']} </div>";
  }
}
else {
  echo "<div class='unavailable'>No Comments Found!</div>";
}
```

It's always good to have this sort of a checking of row counts. **Better checking than falling for coding errors. Best of Luck!**

Comment: This works well, however, is there an easy way to put a message if no results are found?

Comment: Knowledge - Amazing. Thank you!